# Can't install the snap version of Krita on Ubuntu 22.04 because it's unable to install prerequisites

Tags: 22.04, kde, snap, krita

*This appears to be a known issue. Read more on [snapcraft forums](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/global-auto-connect-request-kde-content-snap/34251/5).*

---

I've tried to install Krita using the command `snap install krita`, as I get the following error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Ensure prerequisites for "krita" are available (cannot install prerequisite "kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20": no snap revision available as specified)
```

I've tried to look up this kde-frameworks snap, but the message I got back is:

```
error: no snap found for "kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20"
```

It also doesn't show up in the snap store software on my desktop, but I can find it online on snapcraft.io at https://snapcraft.io/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20

When I try to open up the snap store from the website using the direct install link, I get the error message

```
failed to install: not supported
```

in the desktop application. When I try to use the code `sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20`, the message is

```
   error: snap "kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20" is not available on stable but is available to
   install on the following channels:

   candidate  snap install --candidate kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20
   beta       snap install --beta kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20
   edge       snap install --edge kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20

   Please be mindful pre-release channels may include features not completely tested or
   implemented. Get more information with 'snap info kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20'.
```

However, none of the three code works, they all return similar messages as above.

I've found many other versions of kde-frameworks, with similar naming structures as this one on the snap store app, but installing one (I went with `kde-frameworks-5-102-qt-5-15-8-core22` as it seemed to be a newer version going by the name) didn't make any difference.

What am I missing, why doesn't it work?

Comment: It's a known issue, and is being dealt with - https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/global-auto-connect-request-kde-content-snap/34251

Comment: Thank you, good to know I'm not the only one

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the apt version: `sudo apt update; sudo apt install krita`?

Comment: Ah yes there is, I forgot to mention: the apt version is somewhat outdated - I’d prefer the latest release

Comment: You could use the appimage provided [here](https://krita.org/en/download/krita-desktop/).

Comment: I'll probably do that for the time being. I wanted to use the snap version since I use snap blender, and I thought I might as well transition to snaps if the apt versions aren't getting the same updates, and ubuntu is pushing snaps anyways. Seems like I chose just the right time to try it...